# how to get distinct objects from an array containing many instances of the same object

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an array (`itemArray`) that contains a number of objects. Each of these objects, which we'll refer to as `item` objects, has a property containing an item identifier that tells what type of item it is. We'll call that one `IID`.

Now, the user is going to be using the application to add instances of `item` to `itemArray`, and the user may add several identical instances (for example, 4 `item`s, each with an `IID` of 3). Eventually, `itemArray` is going to contain arguably hundreds of instances of `item`, and those instances will be added in no particular order, and there could be several instances that are identical to other instances in the array (4 `item`s with an `IID` of 3, 2 `item`s with an `IID` of 6, etc etc).

I need to create an array (let's call it `tempArray`) that will be able to give a summary of the objects in the array based on the `IID`. I don't need to count the objects of each type in `itemArray`, I just need to add 1 instance of `item` to `tempArray` for each type of `item` in `itemArray`.

So, for example:

If my `itemArray` looks like this:

```
item.IID = 4
item.IID = 3
item.IID = 4
item.IID = 6
item.IID = 4
item.IID = 5
item.IID = 6
item.IID = 3`
```

Then I need `tempArray` too look like this:

```
item.IID = 4
item.IID = 3
item.IID = 6
item.IID = 5
```

Where `tempArray` just shows the variety of objects in `itemArray` based on the `IID`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're not really trying to sort? And is IID item's only property?

Comment: I'm not trying to sort, really, so maybe the question title is a little bit misleading. I'm just trying to get tempArray to represent the variety of items in itemArray. The order that they go in isn't important. And item has other properties besides IID.

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that an `item` is equal to another `item` based on their `IID`s, I would implement the `isEqual` method checking the `IID`s (returning `YES` if they're the same) and then use a `NSSet` to get the "filtered" list (once you have mentioned in your comment that the order isn't important to you). Like this:

```
@implementation YourItem

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object
{
    if (self != object) 
        return NO;

    if (![self.class isKindOfClass:[object class]]) 
        return NO;

    return self.IID == object.IID;
}

@end
```

As remembered by @jlehr, you need to override `- (NSUInteger)hash` too. You can do this by implemeting something like this:

```
- (NSUInteger)hash
{
    /* every property that will make it equals to another object */
    return [self.IID hash] ^ [self.name hash] /* ... ^ */;
}
```

(There is a [great post](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html) written by Mike Ash explaining in full details Equality and Hashing)

and then...

```
NSSet *tempSet = [NSSet setWithArray:itemArray];
```

and if you want to convert it to a `NSArray` again:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [tempSet allObjects];
```

Comment: You might want to update your answer to point out that when overriding `isEqual:`, you must also override `hash`.

Comment: Thanks to remember me @jlehr

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, I would solve this using NSDictionary and would insert an item only if the key does not exist (item.iid is the key of the dictionary).

you can ask the dictionary if it has the object or it has the key, both works fine.

Comment: Additionally, the dictionary can return all the keys (`allKeys`) it contains and all the values (`allValues`) it contains as `NSArray` instances.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create NSSet from your array and then create NSArray from NSSet.

NSSet *tempSet = [NSSet setWithArray:yourArray];
NSArray *tempArray = [tempSet allObjects];